# How to change to a specific openoffice document in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, workflow

Imaging I have three opened documents in Openoffice Writer and I want to go to one of them, in stardard gnome I would have three applications in the bottom panel each with their correspondent name.

In dockbarx, hovering the mouse would show me each of the three documents. Now in Unity if I click in the launcher will take me to one of the documents, I suppose is taking me to the last one I was editing or reading, and then I have to click in the Window Menu to choose a different document (this workflow is very inefficient).

I wasn't able to figure out the way of going to a specific document.
Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are working with another program, the first time that you click on the openoffice icon, all open documents should go to the foreground (this is only useful if you have not maximised documents). If you click on the icon again, it will show you all open the documents. You can choose there which one you want to focus.

If you are already in OpenOffice, clicking on its icon in unity should open the document selection window.

Comment: Personally, this fits my work-flow better than a selection list. Probably because I usually want the last open window, that way it's one click less most of the time and one click more sometimes.

Comment: Thanks, Javier, that's what I was looking for. When all the documents are shown I realized that I can move though all of them with the cursor key which is good but as I move the doc should change the brightness or something like that because the only way to know in which doc I am is looking at the title that is shown in the panel. Another thing is that every window should have a small close button like the ones that are shown in html overlays so we can close one document directly, otherwise we have to choose that document and then close it.

Comment: The way DockbarX does it isn't a selection list _instead_ of opening the last used window on click. The list is shown on hovering and you can set clicking behavior to open the last used window (multiple clicking will then cycle through the windows of the app in the order they were last used). Default behavior is to bring up all windows of the app when clicked.

Comment: @Korcia, you should probably open a bug with all those ideas. I like a lot the close button one. @M75: This is a great behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

For this situation I would use the "Spread Mode" keyboard short-cut.

Press the Super + W key (i.e. the windows symbol button and the w key)

This will display all open windows on the same screen.  You can then click which ever document you now wish to work on.

Answer (score 0):

3 other solutions, I like the Super+W key suggestion, did not know that one!

ALT TAB will allow you to quickly choose the file you need. Keep ALT key Pressed, The TAB key is to select, release when the correct document is selected.

or

On the menu bar of OpenOffice click Window, and choose the document you need.

or

Right click on each document title bar and send it to a different workplace. Then Use CTRL ALT Left arrow key, or CTRL ALT Right arrow key to move between workplaces. Oops question is about Unity, so this one might not work.